# scp lost connection and timet out error linux

Tags: linux, scp

I am new to Linux and file transfer processes via scptrying to use `scp` between two Linux servers. I already installed SSH for both of them, and it is working. I also enabled PasswordAuthentication but got no results.

```
scp codesgcc.txt user@ip:/home/
ssh: connect to host ip port 22: Connection timed out
lost connection
```

when I try `service sshd status` to check if SSH works:

```
ssh.service - OpenBSD Secure Shell server
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/ssh.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Sun 2023-06-11 10:48:37 EEST; 13h ago
       Docs: man:sshd(8)
             man:sshd_config(5)
   Main PID: 23254 (sshd)
      Tasks: 1 (limit: 9320)
     Memory: 2.3M
        CPU: 126ms
     CGroup: /system.slice/ssh.service
             └─23254 "sshd: /usr/sbin/sshd -D [listener] 0 of 10-100 startups"

Jun 11 10:48:37 Lenovo-Z50-70 systemd[1]: Starting OpenBSD Secure Shell server...
Jun 11 10:48:37 Lenovo-Z50-70 sshd[23254]: Server listening on 0.0.0.0 port 22.
Jun 11 10:48:37 Lenovo-Z50-70 sshd[23254]: Server listening on :: port 22.
Jun 11 10:48:37 Lenovo-Z50-70 systemd[1]: Started OpenBSD Secure Shell server.
Jun 11 10:51:27 Lenovo-Z50-70 sshd[23877]: Accepted password for husamettin from ipaddress port 58792 ssh2
Jun 11 10:51:27 Lenovo-Z50-70 sshd[23877]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session opened for user husamettin(uid=1000) by (uid=0)
```

Comment: Is this command working `ssh user@ip hostname` ?

Comment: @Philippe : "I already installed SSH for both of them, and it is working."* . (2nd sentence).

Comment: But sorry, this isn't about `if/then/else` programming code. Please delete here and repost to [su] . (I didn't downvote your Q, but am voting-to-close). Good luck.

Comment: Your description leaves a few questions open. When you say **I already installed SSH for both of them, and it is working.** ... what does that mean - you see the `sshd` is running? Can you connect to each server locally? What is the firewalling like? Which distro are you using? Are both servers on the same subnet? Are there any firewall appliances between them?

Comment: How do you know `sshd` is working on both machines? Have you ssh'ed into either of them? If `ssh user@ip` works, then `scp somefile.ext user@ip:/home/username` should also work.

Comment: @shellter Is that statement clear for you ? Not for me.

Comment: @Philippe : Yes it was clear to me that the O.P. can connect via ssh between both machines. YRMV. Good luck to all.